# How to access ASP.NET App Over a Network Using IP Address

Tags: asp.net

My asp.net web app is hosted on this URL on my local machine:

```
http://localhost:45433/
```

I want to access the same application from a different computer on the network. I tried replacing the localhost with my IP but it did not work.

any ideas!

**UPDATE 1:**

Now, I am getting this error:

Login failed for user ''. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.

Comment: You need a web server.  Are you the network administrator?

Comment: got it! Thanks everyone! SO ROCKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, add the application as a virtual in IIS, and as long as you can access the machine on the network, you can do:

```
http://<machine name>/<virtual>
```

I do that at work, where I can access my co-worker's web site.

HTH.

Answer (score 3):

If your application is hosted using Visual Studio's built in web development server then this server does not allow remote connections. It is for testing purposes only and accepts connections only from localhost. In order to access your application from remote clients you might need to deploy it to IIS.

Answer (score 0):

That looks a lot like a url used by the development web server in visual studio.  That web server only responds to requests from the localhost.  It won't work for other requests from other machines on your network.

You need to install IIS on your machine (must be a Pro version of Windows) and deploy to that IIS install to share your app on the network.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the built-in version of Cassini (VS debug server) allows remote connections.

However, the [UltiDev version](http://ultidev.com/Products/Cassini/), built off of the same code base with a few enhancements, does, and is a much lighter-weight install than IIS (especially if you can't find your OS install DVD). It also integrates nicely with Visual Studio for debugging purposes.